# ContextMenu Does not Dissappear On Another Right Click

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, java-8

I have made a `ContextMenu` for handling right clicks, but when I right click again the original does not disappear.

Code:

```
this.table.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, (event) -> {
        if (event.getButton() == MouseButton.SECONDARY) {
            MenuItem delete = new MenuItem("Delete");
            delete.setOnAction((actionEvent) -> {
                Action action = Dialogs.create().nativeTitleBar().title("Are you sure?").masthead("This member will be removed from the table")
                        .message("Are you sure that you want to remove "
                                + this.table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().memberProperty.get().get()
                                + " from the table?").showConfirm();
                if (action == Dialog.Actions.YES || action == Dialog.Actions.OK) {
                    this.table.getItems().remove(this.table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
                }
            });
            ContextMenu menu = new ContextMenu(deleteMember);
            menu.show(this.table, event.getScreenX(), event.getScreenY());
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright it looks like it's the line where the context menu is assigned that was the problem. I did `menu.show(this.table.getScene().getWindow(), event.getScreenX(), event.getScreenY());` and this made everything work. I'm guessing that what was causing the problem was a lower level working of whatever is assigned to the owner variable.